# Create a Table based on results of a column of data in another worksheet and eliminate null values

Tags: arrays, excel

To set this up....I have roughly 12,000 rows of data that captures sales detail activity. I have an Excel function in a column to the right of the data that identifies the invoice number based on unique qualifiers (if the transcation meets the qualifier it lists the invoice number and, if not, assigns ""). Of the 12,000 rows of data maybe 50 will qualify. I then need to use the invoice numbers that qualify to pull sales and COGS data for all those invoices that match the qualifying invoice numbers (another explanation is necessary at this point....an invoice that qualifies will be listed twice....once that contains the information that identifies whetehr it qualifies but that row will have no sales data and a second time with thye dsales data...I do not know why it does it this way. So, in other words, the row of data with the sales information I need to capture does not contain the data that allows me to recognize that an invoice qualifies). Each mopnth adds the current month's sales data to the population...so, 12,000 rows this month and it will be 16,000 next month and so on.

I was hoping to create a table that pulls only the qualifuying invoice numbers from the sales data (it would basically create a table of 50 (in my example) while ignoring the 11,950 rows where the cell equals ""). I can do a simple pivot table but next month I need it to recognize the new population of data and update based on the additional rows of new monthly data as well as the rows of data from prior months.

Any soultions/ideas are much appreciated!